# How to set target values as next row rather the current row in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm creating a basic application to predict the 'Close' value of a stock for day n+1, given features of stock n.

I currently define my features and targets as so

```
features = df.loc[:,df.columns != 'Close']
targets = df.loc[:,df.columns  == 'Close']
```

Where targets are the data in the data frame where the column is called 'Close', and the features are those in the data frame where the column isn't called 'Close'

This gives me a fairly accurate prediction which would make sense as the Close value is likely to not differ much from the current day's open, low and high values, however I want to use model to predict the value of Close for day n+1, where n is the day, given features in n.

Comment: then you should have excluded current day's open low and high values from features

Answer (score 0):

You can apply `df_plus1 = df.shift(-1)` function from pandas to get the dataframe of the next day.

It would create a df with same dimensions with shifted rows.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'd then have features as the same, but targets = df.loc[:,df_plus1.columns  == 'Close']? Also if my Cross validation scores is 0.949, and training set score is 1.00, I'm probably doing something else wrong?